# Center Text Vertical In Element That changes Height and Width

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZeVXG

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="col-inner">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450" />
 <div class="content">
   <h3>Hello World</h3>
   <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
 </div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
img{
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
.col-inner{
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}
.content{
 position: absolute;
 width: 90%;
 height: 90%;
 top: 5%;
 left: 5%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
 color: #FFF;
 text-align: center;
}
```

I've tried a bunch of techniques found on Stack Overflow but everything seems to work only if you know the width and height. Both of those properties will change as you flex the browser. Is there any way to keep the text centered vertically the whole way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center an element horizontally and vertically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score 2):

I found this trick on stackoverflow as well, I will add a link as soon as i find it again:

```
height: auto; // (this is the default)
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

That works because `translateY` takes the height of the element, and `top` uses the height of the surrounding element.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zNJvgg

Answer (score 0):

You should try and use `flexbox` and if possible make some changes in your html.

In my opinion, to make this work I would use:

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="col-inner">
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Hello World</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
    .col-inner{
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/450x450');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
.content{
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

I just added the the image as `background-image` for the tag that acts as a container, and used `display: flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center` to horizontally & vertically center the text and all the elements inside the container.

You can tweak the `height` of `.col-inner` and see that no matter what height the class has, it will always be centered.

I've set a codepen to play with it: [code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygxOyY)

Keep in mind that if you want to use `flexbox` you should prefix your code. Use this website [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/) to see what prefixes you should add to `flexbox` and related properties.